# Send email with contents of text box in one button in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, basic

Part of an application I am making, I wish to make a one button click email sender which will send me a copy of what the user has put in a text box.
I don't want them to mess around with having to fill out forms of the email to send it to.

Any Ideas on how to impliment this?
(I'm using Visual Basic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      ' Set the caption bar text of the form.   
      Me.Text = "tutorialspoint.com"
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Try
          Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
          Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
          Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
          Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password")
          Smtp_Server.Port = 587
          Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
          Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

          e_mail = New MailMessage()
          e_mail.From = New MailAddress(txtFrom.Text)
          e_mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text)
          e_mail.Subject = "Email Sending"
          e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
          e_mail.Body = txtMessage.Text
          Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
          MsgBox("Mail Sent")

      Catch error_t As Exception
          MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
      End Try

   End Sub
```

source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_send_email.htm

Replace Smtp_Server.credentials with your own gmail email and password.

There's also a lot of tutorials on YouTube that you can check out if you search for "visual basic email sender".